# Javascript chain rule, return specific value instead of [Object object] [x]

Tags: javascript, return-value, simulation, chain

The question is at the title, but first please look at this code:

```
function number(a) {
    return {
        add: function(b) {
            result = a + b;
            return this;
        }, substract(b) {
            result = a - b;
            return this;
        }
}
```

These code above are simple example of chain rule. I retun an object so I can do it continuously:

```
number(2).add(5).add(3 * 12).substract(Math.random());
```

My problem is, I have to retun an object to keep the function chainable. I'd like to immitate the chain rule, but to return specific value. For instance `number(2).add(3)` would return 5.

Any suggestion is highly appreciated.

Thanks everyone in advanced.
[x]

Answer (score 6):

One way to make a numeric value like 5 "chainable" is to *define a method on the appropriate prototype object*, such as `Number.prototype`. For instance:

```
Number.prototype.add = function (n) {
   return this + n
}

(5).add(2) // 7
5.0.add(2) // 7
5..add(2)  // 7
((5).add(2) + 1).add(34) // okay! 42
```

The syntax above is funny because `5.add(2)` is invalid: JavaScript is expecting a number (or "nothing") after `5.`. Because *this is a global side-effect* (it will *affect all numbers*), care should be taken to avoid unexpected interactions.

<del>The only other</del> Another way to make "5" chain-able is to create a new `Number` object (5 is not a real Number instance, even though it uses Number.prototype!) and then copy over required methods. (I used to think this was the only other way, but see KooiInc's answer -- however, I am not sure how well-defined returning a non-string from `toString` is.)

```
function ops(a) {
  return {
    add: function(b) {
      var res = new Number(a + b) // important!
      var op = ops(res)
      res.add = op.add // copy over singletons
      return res
    }
  }
}
function number(a) {
  return ops(a)
}

number(5).add(2) + 1           // 8
(number(5).add(2) + 1).add(34) // error! add is not a function
```

However, keep in mind this introduces subtle issues:

```
typeof 5                        // number
typeof new Number(5)            // object
5 instanceof Number             // false
new Number(5) instanceof Number // true
```

And this is why we need a `Number` (search SO for "primitives" in JavaScript):

```
x = 5
x.foo = "bar"
x.foo // undefined
```

Furthermore, in conjunction with cwolves' answer, consider:

```
function number (n) { 
  if (this === window) { // or perhaps !(this instanceof number)
    return new number(n)
  } else {
    this.value = n
  }
}
```

Then both `new number(2)` and both `number(2)` will evaluate to a *new* number object.

```
number(2).value     // 2
new number(2).value // 2
number(2) instanceof number     // true
new number(2) instanceof number // true
```

Happy coding.

Comment: +1. This one works correctly, but kind of complex. And I think it's the handy way to do it, I learned a lot from this example. I have something confusing here, the line `res.add = op.add` did you copy the method add from ops(number) to res.add and then return it? If you do so, what happened if you have more than just one method to chain? [x]

Comment: @xx3004 Many frameworks come with an ["extend"](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.extend/) method which can copy over a bunch of properties at once. (Because it is tedious to do `res.add = op.add; res.subtract = op.subtract`, etc. :-) In that example, however, note that each time `op` is invoked, a new set of functions is created. While likely not a concern, this creates much more garbage and data bound in closures than the approach using the prototype.

Answer (score 3):

You have two options.  You can return new objects:

```
function number(a){
    return this instanceof number ? (this.value = a, this) : new number(a);
}

number.prototype = {
    valueOf : function(){
        return this.value;
    },
    add : function(b){
        return new number(this.val + b);
    },
    subtract : function(b){
        return new number(this.val - b);
    }
};
```

or you can modify the existing one (mostly the same code as above, this is different):

```
add : function(b){
    this.value += b;
    return this;
},
```

The difference is in how they act:

```
var x = new number(5),
    y = x.add(10);

// with first example
// x == 5, y == 15


// with 2nd example
// x == 15, y == 15, x === y
```

Comment: Hi cwolves. It works now. But I'm wondering if there is any otherway to chain the functions (like jQuery) and return specific value without creating a new object? I mean `x = number(2).add(2).add(3)` instead of `x = new number(2); x.add(2).add(3)`? [x]

Comment: @xx3004 - make the return statement from the constructor: `return this instanceof number ? this : new number(a);`.  Modified sample to reflect

Comment: @cwolves I'd move the check up to the top of the function to avoid duplicate work in the "non-new" case (even though it is so trivial in this example). It also keeps the intent from "hiding" in single trailing ternary condition :)

Comment: @cwolves Ahh, was looking at the comment, not updated code. I just find the updated code "too clever" :)

Comment: @pst - I've had people criticize me on using commas like that before :)  Anyway, point taken.  If the constructor is actually complicated it would make more sense to put `if(!this instanceof number){ return new number(a); }` at the top of the constructor

Comment: Weird, your example code just return an `[Object object]` not a specific value when I run `number(4).add(2).add(4)`. I'm still trying to make it work because it's from my original chain simulation, I can edit my code much easier than using any other way. [x]

Answer (score 3):

If you define the value as property (`this.a`) and use `toString` within the returned Object, you can chain the methods:

```
function number(a) {
    return {
        a: Number(a) || 0, //if not a, or a===NaN, default = 0
        add: function(b) {
            this.a += b;
            return this;
        },
        subtract: function(b){
            this.a -= b;
            return this;
        },
        valueOf: function(){
          return Number(this.a);
        },
        toString: this.valueOf
    }
}

var n = number(5);
alert(number.add(5).add(2).subtract(2)); //=> 10
alert(number.add(0.5));                  //=> 10.5
alert(number(2).add(5).add(3 * 12).subtract(Math.random());
                                         //=> 42.36072297706966
```

Comment: +1 Clever (the case of `number(5) + 3`, which should be shown above, results in 8 -- at least in FireFox 4). Do you know if/where returning a non-String from `toString` is well-defined?

Comment: valueOf should be used instead of toString, per my example :)

Comment: @all: actually just `valueOf` won't work, but you can force `toString` to use `valueOf` - see my edit. This is a nice article on object to primitive conversion: http://www.adequatelygood.com/2010/3/Object-to-Primitive-Conversions-in-JavaScript

Comment: This one works perfectly as I expected, but I still don't get it why the line toString: this.valueOf is too important? I didn't even see you call it, so what is it for? [x]

Comment: @xx3004 Very nice linked article. For some reason I thought those (conversion functions) were only internally defined ... silly me.

Comment: Every Object (well actually as far as I know, Boolean) has the toString function, I guess that line is used to overwrite it? But I'm not sure and I'm still looking for an answer, what that line does `toString: this.valueOf`? [x]